# Destroying the session of a user in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

How do i destroy a session in ASP.NET and on destroying the session when I click the back button of the browser, it should redirect me to the log in page.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the FAQ section. If you expect any help with any topic, we expect you to show some effort as well. We are here to help, not to do the work for you http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You may use this event to handle your session. I hope it will help you.

```
protected void HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();//It clears the session when the user logged out.
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Comment: You dont have to use that, I assume that you use webforms.

Answer (score 0):

call [Session.Abandon()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to destroy it.